# What is the equivalent of (+)<2 in ANSI SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ansi-sql

I want to turn this

```
TableA.ColumnA(+)<2
```

into ANSI SQL.

I already tried:

```
(TableA.ColumnA<2 OR TableA.ColumnA IS NULL)
```

It missed one row. Despite the fact that its ColumnA is (null).

Edit (more context):
Here is the query

```
SELECT * FROM a, c 
WHERE a.status(+)<2
AND a.rank(+)=1
AND c.id=a.id(+)
```

Comment: If that's a joining condition then you need to use a `LEFT`, `RIGHT` or `FULL OUTER JOIN` to make this condition work. An `INNER JOIN` will not help in this case.

Comment: It's of course some type of condition, but there is no `TableB` to join to. I don't understand this condition at all. In my understanding there has to be a table next to the < instead of a number.

Comment: You need to show more context, so we have a clue what you're asking about so we can suggest a replacement; without more context, this question is difficult to answer. It's like asking "why doesn't a=b?" with no additional information. You need to be more specific and provide more details.

Comment: Hi Ken. I've added the full query. I hope it's specific enough.

Comment: Should that be `c.id=a.id(+)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a try

```
SELECT * FROM c LEFT JOIN a
ON c.id = a.id
AND a.status < 2
AND a.rank = 1
```

Comment: There is no `TableB` in my case. Why would I join a Table to a number? Cause that's what `TableA.ColumnA(+)<2` do in my humble opinion.

Comment: ekip, the idea is to take the sample query and apply it to your situation. Obviously your schema doesn't literally have a `TableB`. I hope my edit helps you to see.

Comment: Thanks M.Ali and Jeffrey! It turned out, that you are right.